# Recommended WebRTC Server Configuration for Native app (iOS/Android)?

Tags: webrtc, server

I tried to build a server for integrating the webrtc native APIs in an native app, but I am not sure about how the server should be configured, like the ICE/STUN/TURN, signaling, media server etc..
So far as I know is the open source project: https://github.com/priologic/easyrtc
Can anybody give some recommendations?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a WebRTC infrastructure, there are several things involved. The client part is written in JavaScript and runs on the browser.

But as you said it is a server side part. First there is a ICE/STUN/TURN server that it's used for a client to discover its public IP address if it is located behind a NAT. Depending on your requirements could not be necessary to build/deploy your own server, but use an already public (and free) existing one - [here](https://gist.github.com/yetithefoot/7592580)'s a list. You can also deploy an open source one like [Stuntman](http://www.stunprotocol.org/).

Then it comes the signaling part, used by two clients to negotiate and start a webrtc session. There is no standard here and you have a few options.

You can use an XMPP server with a Jingle extension. You can deploy an existing XMPP server, like [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/index.jsp) or [Tigase](http://www.tigase.org/)

You can also use SIP, a protocol much more encountered for VoIP. You can use [JAIN-SIP](https://jsip.java.net/) or [SIP Servlets](https://github.com/Mobicents/sip-servlets).

Or you can develop your own signaling protocol using something like websockets.

The server side options that I was giving you were Java based ones, but you can find similar for other infrastructures too.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestion, I will try them later. I see you are working on WebRTC too, so if you can share some information about how to collaborate the native app with server, I will be very grateful.

Comment: I suppose you want to implement WebRTC in a native app, but using something like PhoneGap. Because in the end for WebRTC you'll need a browser.

In this case the problem is that Phonegap still uses the browser and for iOS is not supported: http://caniuse.com/#search=webrtc.

But it seems that there is a plugin: https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc, but I never used it.

Comment: I am planning to implement the native app without help of PhoneGap, just thinking of using the android/iOS' native APIs for performance consideration and UI design, because there are already samples included in webrtc trunk, I think the signaling flow etc. should be changed from samples however. Without a workable server, the developing and debugging of the APP side would be impossible so I posted to seek help from you all. I am still working on deploying the server. Thanks for your kindly advices.

Comment: I never used webrtc in a native app. Supposing that it's using the same implementation as the one from the web server, I doubt that you will have significant performance gains.

Comment: So far as I know, the signaling process is basically the same, however, as the apprtc example, the call starts from creating a chat room, the process is not so flexible in case of native app, so I think this kind of alteration is necessary. To woking out the new state machine, I need a new workable server rather than apprtc. I will try to figure out, please let me consult server problems in the progress, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

STUN/TURN is required. Use public ones (not absolutely stable) or get a Ubuntu machine ans install from the source: https://code.google.com/p/rfc5766-turn-server/

Signaling is trivial. You just forward messages between peers. Just build a simple chat server.

Media server is whole different story and require sophisticated client-server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your advices about STUM/TURN server. I had some experience with SIP, but not so sure about the media server, so can you give more advices on the media server. I am considering supporting both the relay and p2p mode.

Comment: In my opinion, you should use SIP only if you have it already in your infrastructure. Using it only for WebRTC signaling, I think it's an overkill.